# Multiples routes between two hosts

Tags: networking, centos, routing, linux-networking

I have the following network structure, where there are two hosts (Master and Slave) that are **not** in the same network, but there are some "Mid" hosts that share networks with both Master and Slave. All hosts are running CentOS.

[image: Diagram]

I need to have comms between Master and Slave, so I started with Mid2, enabling ip forwarding and configuring the ip tables. I also added a static route in Master to Slave via Mid2, and viceversa. So far everything worked. The configuration is as follows:

Config at slave:

```
[user@slave] $ ip r 
192.168.10.150 via 192.9.202.52 dev ens3f0
```

Config at master:

```
[user@master] $ ip r
192.9.202.242 via 192.168.10.52 dev bond0
```

Config at mid2:

```
[user@mid2] $ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
[user@mid2] $ iptables -L
...

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  192.9.202.242        192.168.10.150
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.10.150       192.9.202.242
```

After that, I tried replicating the same config with the rest of the hosts, but it started to fail:

```
# ip r add 192.9.202.242 via 192.168.10.51  dev bond0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

Then I did it using different metrics for each route. However once everything was configured for both mid1 and mid2, there was no ping.

The question is, is this even possible? Can I have multiple "options" for routing comms to a remote host? How can I do it?

Comment: `RTNETLINK answers: File exists` indicates that the route (obviously) already exists. You can add several routes with different metric. But actually, it probably will not accomplish what you are trying to do.
You do only need one route (e.g. through mid2) for master and slave being reachable by each other.
If you want to have routes through mid1/mid3 to have backups in case mid2 fails, you'll need a dynamic routing protocol.
I suggest to restructure the network, create 3 IP networks and put a router (or a router cluster) in between instead of routing through the hosts.

Comment: @jose i should probably comment that the network setup you're describing is exactly the type of birds nest network madness that i've spent a large part of my career going into companies to clean up. Use a router, future you will thank you for it.

Comment: typically people use dedicated gateways for that instead of those “mids”. One gateway doesn’t have any of those issues but becomes single point of failure. That’s why redundant gateways schemas are applied.

Comment: I agree with those who say that it's better to use a dedicated router as the router, rather than use arbitrary hosts that happen to be in the middle as ad-hoc routers.  You would only use the above topology if there were other considerations forcing it, that are beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Please edit the question to state why you want to configure multiple routes.  Is it for robustness or for load sharing, or both?  Or is there some other reason?

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose in having multiple routes is robustness (redundancy in case of failure of a mid node), run OSPF on all five nodes.  One option is [Quagga](https://www.quagga.net/), which provides OSPF and other routing protocols for for various Linux flavors including CentOS.

Running OSPF on the nodes makes each one of them a router, and communications between master and slave will automatically switch to another mid system if the one they are using fails.

If your purpose is to load balance across the three routes, see Nikita Kipriyanov's answer regarding ECMP.  Note that you'll get load balancing only if you have multiple streams (for example, multiple TCP connections, or UDP connections between different ports) or if you specifically configure ECMP hashing to hash on something that is different for different packets.  (I'm not versed in what Linux permits for ECMP hashing configuration.)  Or have three different IP addresses on one end.

If you want both benefits (load sharing and robustness) then you need both solutions, but configuring ECMP will be different if you use OSPF (you'll configure OSPF to do it rather than defining static routes.)

Note that the mid systems won't be particularly good/fast routers, so @Bernhard 's idea to restructure and add an actual router between them is probably a better solution.  But if the bandwidth requirements are low and you want to avoid restructuring the network or adding new equipment, this can work with what you have.

Answer (score 1):

In general, what you depicted is exactly an [ECMP route](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-cost_multi-path_routing). Although dynamic routing protocols can (and will) install such routes, if you don't expect your network topology to change, running an dynamic routing protocol adds complexity and I feel that is an overkill. OSPF is not a piece of cake, trust me.

Sure, you can install such route by hand:

```
ip route add 192.9.202.242 proto static scope global \
    nexthop dev ens2f0 via 192.168.10.51 weight 1 \
    nexthop dev ens2f0 via 192.168.10.52 weight 1 \
    nexthop dev ens2f0 via 192.168.10.53 weight 1
```

And vice versa on reverse side.

There are many options, you see one of them here - weight, but there are also other. Cumulus networks articles like [this one](https://cumulusnetworks.com/blog/celebrating-ecmp-part-two/) in general are a good information source about Linux networking.

Comment: I disagree with the use of the term ECMP, which is for load balancing and not route redundancy.  With ECMP, different flows take different paths, but all paths must be up.  If a path goes down, routes need to be recalculated; otherwise traffic for flows on that path goes into a black hole.

Comment: ECMP, Equal Cost Multi Path, is when we have multuple ways to reach destination, all of which are loaded equally. There is nothing about auto calculation in this abbreviation per se. Yes, is usually implemented with dynamic routing, which doesn't mean that it is a part of dynamic routing. Also, nowhere in the question we have requirements of what could be done with those paths, so we are free to choose simplest solution (just two commands! Compare that with 5 OSPF daemons). If you read carefully, I actually guarded against path breaking with "...don't expect network topology to change...".

Comment: After re-reading, I see that the OP doesn't say why multiple routes are desired.  If the reason is to load balance, then ECMP is the solution.  If the reason is robustness in case a mid host goes down, a routing protocol is the answer.  If both are desired, then both are needed.  So, I stand corrected, thanks.